# Protected Blu-Ray playback in elementary OS

Tags: videos

Can any of elementary OS 5's video applications play protected Blu-Ray discs?
Everything I've read about getting Blu-Ray to play on Linux looks complex and convoluted.

Thank you for your answers.

The Blu-Ray in question is the Red Dwarf S1-8 collection, and it has some discs encoded with AACS 66 and some with AACS 68.
Discs with 66 can play fine but the 68 discs do not.
Guess I'm just going to have to wait until MakeMKV can support it.

Answer (score 1):

you need to install VLC Library know as libdvdcss to breaks the encryption, you can see the full answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/811071/is-there-an-easy-way-to-watch-blu-ray-in-ubuntu-16-04).

Answer (score 0):

VLC should be able to play anything you throw at it